# How does this step up oscillator actually work?

Tags: oscillator, low-power, energy-harvesting

I watched a Dave jones video on an energy harvester but I'm trying to figure out how the front end of this circuit actually resonates and how that steps up some small input voltage.

**Is it a function of C2 and the inductance of the transformer?**

**Does the frequency that it resonates matter?**

**What powers the self resonating circuit?**

Here is a screen shot of the circuit in question: [image: Step-up oscillator]

The Datasheet can be found [here](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3108fc.pdf)

Comment: I'm guessing this is from the following video, in case anyone wants more context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aSPopIcKLQ

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't resonate - it's a step-up transformer (1:100). Each time the MOSFET switches on Vin gets transferred to the secondary with largely a 100:1 amplification in voltage just like a conventional transformer steps up or steps down (more usually) voltage.

---

ADDITIONAL INFO

Series resonation of the transformer's secondary leakage inductance and C2 cause the circuit to oscillate BUT, conceptually the MOSFET could be driven by an oscillator if one could be found to work at such low voltages.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. So the switch node is powered from somewhere else?

Comment: The MOSFET's gate is controlled by C2, though, which certainly implies it's resonating.

Comment: @NickJohnson what I meant to say is that the energy transfer doesn't rely on resonation - 20mV in x 100 = 2V. The leakage inductance of the secondary and C2 will form a tuned circuit that dictate the self oscillation frequency. Maybe I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: @Andy : minor nitpick ... the secondary leakage inductance and C2 in series with Cgs form a resonant circuit?

Comment: This answer seems to disagree with what's being said in the video... is the video incorrect?

Ref: https://youtu.be/9aSPopIcKLQ?t=998

Comment: @lindes - where's the disagreement?

Comment: "it doesn't resonate" [this answer] vs "a resonant step-up oscillator" [the video]... I dunno, that sounds like disagreement to me.  But this is all new territory to me, so maybe I'm missing some subtlety between the connotations of the verb resonate versus the adjective resonant??!?